# How to find pattern from route string and edit next line in bash shell?

Tags: sed

```
cat test.txt
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
```

Above is target file `test.txt`.I need to find pattern `baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/7/$basearch/`,replace next line **enabled=0** to **enabled=1**.

I tried `sed '@baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/7/$basearch/@!b;n;cenabled=1' test.txt` but failed.

> Notice:CANNOT use other delimeter such as `@` instead of `/` because
>   it's not replacement command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some reason, I could only make it work with a slash as a delimiter, see https://ideone.com/A9JMsv

Comment: You need a backslash before the delimiter if you use a delimiter other than slash for the match (`/`) command. (The `s` substitution command is different; it can take any punctuation as delimiter without any backslash.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,for what reason?

Comment: @kittygirl See  tripleee's comment, it is not a replacement command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk '
/baseurl=http:\/\/repo\.mysql\.com\/yum\/mysql-5\.5-community\/el\/7\/\$basearch\//{
  print
  flag=1
  next
}
flag && /enabled/{
  print "enabled=1"
  flag=""
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code.

Answer (score -1):

This might work out—it finds 'baseurl=' then grabs the next line and substitutes 'enable=0' with 'enabled=1':

```
sed '/baseurl=/ {N;s/enabled=0/enabled=1/;}' test.txt
```

Feel free to change the initial regex to the line you mentioned. I just wanted to show the general solution.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -E '/baseurl=http:\/\/repo\.mysql\.com\/yum\/mysql-5\.5-community\/el\/7\/\$basearch\//!b;n;cenabled=1' test.txt > temp_file && mv temp_file  test.txt
```

This answer come from RavinderSingh13 and WiktorStribiżew,I just comibne it.